# S3 gateway setup problems with elasticsearch v0.19.0

Tags: amazon-s3, elasticsearch

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/22/elasticsearch-on-ec2.html) on setting up elasticsearch on ec2 and I can't get ES to use the S3 gateway.  As the tutorial says I should see [gateway.s3] in the output but I don't.

The tutorial is a little outdated so kimchy told me to use [elasticsearch-cloud-aws](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws).  So I installed cloud-aws with `bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/1.4.0`.  After unsuccessfully hooking up to S3 I found this [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/issues/8) that suggested installing like this `bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws`

I've also played with cloud.aws.region but that didn't help.

So what should I try to get the S3 gateway working?  Might this be an issue with the new 0.19.0 release?

Here is how I set up a micro instance with v0.19.0

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.19.0.zip
sudo unzip elasticsearch-0.19.0.zip -d /usr/local/elasticsearch
cd /usr/local/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.19.0
sudo bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/1.4.0
sudo vim config/elasticsearch.yml 
sudo vim config/logging.yml 
sudo vim config/elasticsearch.yml 
ES_MIN_MEM=400mb
ES_MAX_MEM=400mb
echo $ES_MAX_MEM
sudo bin/elasticsearch -f
sudo vim config/elasticsearch.yml 
... snip
sudo bin/plugin -install Aconex/elasticsearch-head
sudo bin/elasticsearch -f
sudo vim config/elasticsearch.yml 
... snip
sudo bin/plugin -install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws
sudo bin/elasticsearch -f
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch-demo-js
cloud:
        aws:
                access_key: KEY
                secret_key: SECRET_KEY
                region: us-east
        discovery:
                type: ec2
        gateway:
                type: s3
                s3:
                        bucket: es-demo-js
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 1
gateway.recover_after_time: 1m
gateway.expected_nodes: 2
```

logging.yml

```
rootLogger: INFO, console, file
logger:
  # log action execution errors for easier debugging
  action: DEBUG
  # reduce the logging for aws, too much is logged under the default INFO
  com.amazonaws: WARN

  # gateway
  gateway: DEBUG
  #index.gateway: DEBUG

  # peer shard recovery
  #indices.recovery: DEBUG

  # discovery
  discovery: TRACE

  org.apache: WARN

  index.search.slowlog: TRACE, index_search_slow_log_file

additivity:
  index.search.slowlog: false

appender:
  console:
    type: console
    layout:
      type: consolePattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"

  index_search_slow_log_file:
    type: dailyRollingFile
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}_index_search_slowlog.log
    datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd"
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

OUTPUT

```
    ec2-user@ip-xx elasticsearch-0.19.0]$ sudo bin/elasticsearch -f
    [2012-03-18 16:36:10,786][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
    [2012-03-18 16:36:10,791][INFO ][node                     ] [Roma] {0.19.0}[20285]: initializing ...
    [2012-03-18 16:36:10,804][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Roma] loaded [cloud-aws], sites [head]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,672][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Roma] using group [224.2.2.4], with port [54328], ttl [3], and address [null]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,675][DEBUG][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [Roma] using initial hosts [], with concurrent_connects [10]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,676][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [Roma] using ping.timeout [3s]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,682][DEBUG][discovery.zen.elect      ] [Roma] using minimum_master_nodes [-1]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,683][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Roma] [master] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:11,685][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Roma] [node  ] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,400][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] using initial_shards [quorum], list_timeout [30s]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,589][DEBUG][gateway.local.state.shards] [Roma] took 51ms to load started shards state
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,639][DEBUG][gateway.local.state.meta ] [Roma] took 49ms to load state
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,642][INFO ][node                     ] [Roma] {0.19.0}[20285]: initialized
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,642][INFO ][node                     ] [Roma] {0.19.0}[20285]: starting ...
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,703][INFO ][transport                ] [Roma] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]}
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,719][TRACE][discovery                ] [Roma] waiting for 30s for the initial state to be set by the discovery
    [2012-03-18 16:36:12,722][TRACE][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Roma] [4] sending ping request
    [2012-03-18 16:36:14,224][TRACE][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [Roma] [5] sending ping request
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,726][DEBUG][discovery.zen            ] [Roma] ping responses: {none}
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,729][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Roma] new_master [Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,762][TRACE][discovery                ] [Roma] initial state set from discovery
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,762][INFO ][discovery                ] [Roma] elasticsearch-demo-js/KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,763][DEBUG][gateway                  ] [Roma] delaying initial state recovery for [1m]
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,766][INFO ][http                     ] [Roma] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.127.162.192:9200]}
    [2012-03-18 16:36:15,766][INFO ][node                     ] [Roma] {0.19.0}[20285]: started
    [2012-03-18 16:37:15,778][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][0]: allocating [[twitter][0], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]] on primary allocation
    [2012-03-18 16:37:15,778][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][6]: allocating [[twitter][7], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]] on primary allocation
    [2012-03-18 16:37:15,778][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][8]: allocating [[twitter][9], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]] on primary allocation
    [2012-03-18 16:37:15,779][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][10]: allocating [[twitter][11], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]] on primary allocation
    [2012-03-18 16:37:15,779][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][12]: throttling allocation [[twitter][13], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]]] on primary allocation
    [2012-03-18 16:37:16,050][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][0] starting recovery from local ...
    [2012-03-18 16:37:16,138][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][14] starting recovery from local ...
    [2012-03-18 16:37:16,150][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][0] recovery completed from local, took [100ms]
    index    : files           [3] with total_size [86b], took[11ms]
             : recovered_files [0] with total_size [0b]
             : reusing_files   [3] with total_size [86b]
    start    : took [87ms], check_index [0s]
    translog : number_of_operations [0], took [2ms]
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,156][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][1] recovery completed from local, took [18ms]
    index    : files           [3] with total_size [86b], took[0s]
             : recovered_files [0] with total_size [0b]
             : reusing_files   [3] with total_size [86b]
    start    : took [17ms], check_index [0s]
    translog : number_of_operations [0], took [1ms]
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,179][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][2] starting recovery from local ...
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,228][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][4] starting recovery from local ...
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,238][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Roma] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,239][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [Roma] [twitter][3]: allocating [[twitter][3], node[null], [P], s[UNASSIGNED]] to [[Roma][KYVDhYLmSY-u8j4jVD7FaQ][inet[/10.127.162.192:9300]]] on primary allocation
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,243][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][4] recovery completed from local, took [15ms]
    index    : files           [3] with total_size [86b], took[0s]
             : recovered_files [0] with total_size [0b]
             : reusing_files   [3] with total_size [86b]
    start    : took [2ms], check_index [0s]
    translog : number_of_operations [0], took [13ms]
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,308][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][3] starting recovery from local ...
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,312][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][3] recovery completed from local, took [4ms]
    index    : files           [3] with total_size [86b], took[1ms]
             : recovered_files [0] with total_size [0b]
             : reusing_files   [3] with total_size [86b]
    start    : took [2ms], check_index [0s]
    translog : number_of_operations [0], took [1ms]
[2012-03-18 16:37:16,545][DEBUG][index.gateway            ] [Roma] [twitter][2] recovery completed from local, took [366ms]
    index    : files           [11] with total_size [1.2kb], took[2ms]
             : recovered_files [0] with total_size [0b]
             : reusing_files   [11] with total_size [1.2kb]
    start    : took [50ms], check_index [0s]
    translog : number_of_operations [1], took [314ms]
```

Comment: Make sure the YAML is properly formatted, your indentation looks a bit funky around bucket. It may be more failproof to use full namespaces, see eg. https://github.com/karmi/cookbook-elasticsearch/blob/master/templates/default/elasticsearch.yml.erb#L38

Comment: Yeah the default vim settings give some ugly tabs.  Thanks for sending that link.  I was looking at your file and I realized I had gateway nested under cluster.aws.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cluster, cloud, discover, and gateway are all top level objects.  In my original config they were nested below cloud.  Also as bernie suggest I simplified the YAML by using the full namespaces.

This is what I ended up with

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch-demo-js
cloud.aws.access_key: 
cloud.aws.secret_key: 
cloud.aws.discovery.type: ec2
gateway.type: s3
gateway.s3.bucket: es-demo
gateway.recover_after_nodes: 2
gateway.recover_after_time: 1m
gateway.expected_nodes 2
```

Comment: Only my parents call me "bernie" :)